# video is playing in multiple cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, uicollectionviewcell

I have problem with playing video in the collection view cell

1. My problem is I want to play video  in one cell only but it is playing in all cell.
2. cell contains both videos and images.
3. when ever data source is image that time I want images on image view and view must be hidden.
4. when ever data source is video url that time I want images on view and image view must be hidden.

I used following code.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 //[self.collection reloadData];
homeceeCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


UIImage *image;
NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
NSURL *furl;

NSLog(@"indexpath = %ld", (long)row);

if ([app.array1[row] isKindOfClass:[NSURL class]])
{
      furl=app.array1[row];
    cell.movieplayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:app.array1[row]];

    cell.videoview.hidden=NO;
    cell.img.hidden=YES;
    cell.movieplayer.view.frame = cell.img.frame;
    [cell.videoview addSubview:cell.movieplayer.view];

    NSLog(@"%@",cell.movieplayer);
    [cell.movieplayer play];

            NSLog(@"%@",cell.movieplayer);
}
else {
    if ([app.array1[row] isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]]) {
        image= app.array1[row];
          cell.videoview.hidden=YES;
    }
    else {
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:app.array1[row]];
          cell.videoview.hidden=YES;

    }

    cell.img.image = image;
    cell.videoview.hidden=YES;

}

cell.text.text=[app.tarray1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
```

}

- app.array1 is the array which contains both images and video urls.
- cell.img is the image view which I declared in collection view cell.
- cell.videoview is the view which I declared in collection view cell.

please Help me to solve this problem,If the question is not clear leave me comment I will explain.Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Create `UICollectionViewCell` subclass, then you should override `prepeareForReuse` method - to turn cell to default mode and remove all video player stuff. In `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method use your subclass.

**Swift**:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    //set cell to initial state here 
}
```

**Objective-C**:

```
- (void) prepareForReuse
{
    [super prepareForReuse];

    //set cell to initial state here 
}
```

More info you may find in [UICollectionReusableView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionReusableView_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionReusableView/prepareForReuse) class reference.

> Performs any clean up necessary to prepare the view for use again.
>
> When a view is dequeued for use, this method is called before the corresponding dequeue method returns the view to your code. Subclasses can override this method and use it to reset properties to their default values and generally make the view ready to use again.

Comment: thanks for your answer I Want objective c I dont know swift

Comment: wr should i use this

Comment: Cells are reusable, that is why you are seeing video player not only inside 1 cell.

Comment: bro in view did load i have app.array1 array and it is having only images.2.in other view I have video out put url and I am passing that url back and I am adding the url in to the array.now I want to play video in the cell at indexpath 0 and flowed by images in the other cells How to do that,I used above code.

Comment: if cell is not reusable then how can i reuse the cell for printing the images in cell